# Moving captcha between a user registration and a user profile in joomla

Tags: joomla, captcha

I almost have finished setting up a website based on joomla 3.x but I'm not a programmer and I'm stuck on one point and don't know what to do.
I use a registration form in which I use a user registration and a user profile forms. I also have a captcha on but it's not at the very bottom of the page but between the forms.

Could anyone one of help me with it and tell how to change it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's more than one way to do this, here's one option.

What you are wanting to do is create an override and customise the Joomla core output.

(1) Use the template manager to copy components > com_users > registration files from your base Joomla components directory to `/templates/YOUR-TEMPLATE/html/com_users/registration`

See https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager for detailed instructions on this

(2) You'll be editing `/templates/YOUR-TEMPLATE/html/com_users/registration/default.php`, so maybe make a backup because you'll be doing well if you get this first time ;)

(3) Open default.php with your favourite text editor. It looks to me like the output you want to customise is all happening between lines 39-49

How you attack it from here is up to you. You can use web inspector to examine details about all the fields, their IDs and classes.

Instead of the built in loop in default.php you could manually rebuild the form, or you could keep the loop but add some logic to add the captcha control group where you want it.

Good luck!